# Validating user input with try and catch with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate whatever the values of the inputs are using try and catch. Every time the user gives a wrong value I want a a message to appear next to the input box that filled wrong.

The problem is that the every time it executes, the wrong message appears in both input boxes and I don't want to put many conditions. I just want to make it as simple as possible. I don't have a clue what conditions I should use.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var inputArr = [$("#name").val(), $("#lName").val()];
    var regexArr = [new RegExp("\^[a-zA-z]+$"), new RegExp("\^[a-zA-z]+$")];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
      fn(regexArr[i], inputArr[i]);
    } //for loop

    function fn(exp, str) {
      var res = exp.test(str);
      try {
        if (res == false) {
          throw Error("wrong");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
        $("#empty1").fadeIn(3000);
        $("#empty1").html(e);
        $("#empty1").fadeOut(3000);
        $("#empty2").fadeIn(3000);
        $("#empty2").html(e);
        $("#empty2").fadeOut(3000);
      } //try and catch
    } //function
    
  }); //button
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  Name<input id="name"><span id="empty1"></span></br>
  </br>
  Last Name<input id="lName"><span id="empty2"></span></br>
  </br>
  <button id='btn'>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For form validations, its better using Jquery validation plugin. It is very simple and needs Jquery library included in it. Try this https://jqueryvalidation.org/. Please refer this js fiddle also https://jsfiddle.net/jfc62uof/6/

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="myform" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="psw" id="psw">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="rpsw">
      <span id='message'></span>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="save">
   </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $("#myform").validate({
     rules: {
       psw: {
         required: true
       },
       rpsw: {
         equalTo: "#psw"
       }
     }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks really cool but I want to do it using it try and catch, since it is for a school project

Comment: jquery validation comes with its own error handling so that you are not required to write it from scratch. These plugins are used by a large developer community. Please give an upvote if you find it useful

Comment: I know, but the instructor wants us to do it that way since it is for a school project.

Comment: These plugins are used even for banking projects so what is special with this school project? Why you are saying you should use try catch in client side for a school project? If you are very much interested in code review process, install SonarCube and run automated code review process. There are common guidelines for coding. Not only school projects but every projects needs to follow these rules.

Comment: @BimalKumar thank you for SonarCube. Would try to remember it for my projects the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it according to what has been asked of you to do,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn").click(function() {
        var inputArr = [$("#name").val(), $("#lName").val()];
        var regexArr = [new RegExp("\^[a-zA-z]+$"), new RegExp("\^[a-zA-z]+$")];
        for (var i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
          fn(regexArr[i], inputArr[i],i+1);
        } //for loop

        function fn(exp, str, no) {
          var res = exp.test(str);
          try {
            if (res == false) {
              throw Error("wrong");
            }
          } catch (e) {
            //alert(e);
            if($('#err').length==0)
                $("#empty"+no).val('').addClass('error').after('<p style="display:inline;" id="err">'+e+'</p>');
          } //try and catch
        } //function

      }); //button
    });
```

where error class can have css like

```
.error{
 border: 2px solid red;
 background-color: #f7b9d9;
}
```

Comment: Great! Please accept this as the correct answer if it worked for you completely.

Comment: I still have to play with it a bit, hopefully I will get other options, but thank you very much

Comment: Sure. Take care.